# Is it ok to replace Trash button with Done button during editing? (iOS)

Tags: mobile, ios, mobile-application, keyboard, delete

This image explains UX of my app:
[image: normal & editing mode]

There is a view where the user can type a text. User can delete a note with "Trash" button. When user touches the view application switches into the editing mode and the Trash button is replaced with "Done". Done button allows to hide the keyboard (and thus to show "Trash" button).

"Trash" has additional safety: if the user had input any text, confirmation dialog will be shown.
[image: trash confirmation]

The question is: is it ok practice to replace "Trash" with "Done" in this way? Will user misstouch Trash button? Should I place Done button somewhere else?

Comment: Finally I decided to show both "Trash" and "Done" buttons while editing.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the "Done" button is unnecessary, since its only action is to dismiss the keyboard.

You should be able to dismiss the keyboard with a swipe down, and the note should be saved while you type.

Back to your answer: I think that swapping between two buttons is not good, because the user tend to learn button positions and function. If they change, even if in a predictable way, makes this learning process harder.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The done button is not really necessary, but I'm trying to copy behavior of default iOS apps, such as Notes. They are usually have such button, may be to allow a user to view more text area. Also, down swipe not working on iOS.

Comment: I've asked an iOS developer on my team and he said that it's possible to dismiss keyboard if the view is a scrollView or a tableView, using a keyboardDismissMode flag.

Comment: Although I do agree with the done button being unnecessary, I do not think that buttons appearing *in a sensible way* is fine. Applications are dynamic, and we should serve relatable content/buttons when necessary.

Comment: I agree with you on button appearance, but I feel this case is a little different.
In this case, a button takes the place of the other, and this happens while the user is focused on the text, not on the button.
This could lead to accidentally press the wrong action for a distracted user.